# Method which gets data from dataprovider has to be used in another class: Selenium, Java, TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng-dataprovider

Step1: Created a class A with two methods:

```
@Test(dataProvider="testdata")
InputToForm()

@DataProvider(name="testdata")
readDataFromExcel()
```

Step2: Created a class B, where I need to call the method InputToForm() with the data.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Please read about inheritance and more about core java in general before you jump into automation, else you will be stuck at every small issue.

You can resolve your issue by simply using inheritance, as mentioned below.

Your data provider in a different class

```
public class DataLibrary {
    @DataProvider(name="loginData")
    public Object[][] loginData(){
        return new Object[][]{
                {"username", "password"}
        };
    }
}
```

And here goes your login class.

```
public class Login extends DataLibrary {
    @Test(dataProvider = "loginData")
    public void login(String username, String password){
        System.out.println("username="+username+" password="+password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response Gaurang. 
But, my question is how do I use these username and password data into another method which is in another class.

Comment: you mean another method or another test ?? if you are talking about another test, that's what exactly this code does. if you are talking about another method, why not just call that function ??